# Insecure Content Blocked while browsing

Tags: insecure-connection

[insecure content blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4dnC.png)

When I published my site (https://myitside.com/instagram-downloader/), I always get a safety shield in the url-bar on top that says: Insecure content blocked. This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources. Because of this error, my site does not show icons or the correct font until I click "load unsafe scripts".

How to solve this

Answer (score -1):

As it says, your page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources...make sure those scripts are loading from `https://` addresses and not `http://`.

Comment: How? Can you please explain.

Comment: Look at your source code and edit the URLs that appear